# Error Running tesseract-ocr as external command from MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab, ocr, tesseract, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run tesseract 3.04 from matlab using https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html

What is the meaning of the error on line 2 and 3?

```
 1 !tesseract im.tif imTif
 2    >> tesseract: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/liblept.so.5)
 3    >> tesseract: symbol lookup error: tesseract: undefined symbol: _ZN9tesseract19TessBoxTextRendererC1EPKc
```

Tesseract runs properly in the Linux terminal, but I would be able to call the function within a series of MATLAB functions.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it could be a path issue? You may want to try specifying the full path to tesseract? Checking what system path's are available to MATLAB might be illuminating as well: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html

Comment: @DMR , I already added tesseract to the system pack like suggested in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Provisional solution:

Run Matlab from terminal using:

LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" matlab